# Редактирование меню в joomla

Tags: joomla, php

Заказчики сайта попросили два пункта меню (li) выделить среди других, но как это сделать если на главной страницы только модуль а самого меню нет. Как на joomla отредактировать заголовки меню по отдельности, подскажите, возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. 1) версия джумлы, 2) как можно их отредактировать "не по отдельности"?)

Comment: Как на joomla отредактировать заголовки меню **по отдельности**

Comment: сильно) вопрос не так давно задан, а страница уже в индексе гугла) очень актуально по всей видимости)

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что автор вообще не знает как их редктировать :D

Comment: ты вообще с joomla работал?, в курсе про чё я говорю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li class="itemXXX">Item</li>
//где ХХХ номер!
//в CSS
.itemXXX { css properties; }
```

В подробностях... 
У элементов меню есть свой порядковый номер который задается как class *item777* к примеру.
В css задать нужные свойства этому классу!)

Comment: дело в том что на самой странице <ul><li></li></ul> нет, есть только модуль который создаёт это при отображение страницы

Comment: ну так модуль создает уже готовый вам класс, осталось задать ему свойства в css! Пример тут http://shafran.ua/ слева первые три ссылки так и сделаны, арабское название пункта меню ведет ту да же что и русское, по факту имеет тот же html но собственные свойства css!

> Заказчики сайта попросили

жесть)))

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно использовать чистый CSS3 либо jquery. Существует еще порядковый номер элемента в наборе.